# Are there special Halachos for homeowners?

Tags: halacha, real-estate, home-house, ownership

As people progress through life, they hope to reach many milestones. They (in no particular order) become an adult, get married, get a job, have kids, etc. As an Orthodox Jew, we're aware that each stage of life comes with it's own set Halachos and challenges, and we do our best to learn how to meet them.

One of life's milestones is becoming a homeowner for the first time. Generally, one grows up in the home of a parent or guardian, and slowly transitions into more independent living, often starting with living in a rented location.

Many people hope to one day transition into owning their own home. When one reaches that exciting moment in their life, are there any laws that they need to be aware of that had never applied to them before?

In short: are there any Halachos that apply only to one who owns a house (as opposed to renting or simply living in a house)?

Comment: Been  thinking about this for a while, wanted to see if anyone else had thoughts about this. I was wondering if perhaps things like Ma'akeh or destroying a fruit tree were only applicable if you own the property, but haven't had a chane to really look deeper.

Comment: According to R. Moshe Feinstein (OC vol.3 §86), and others, only a homeowner is obligated to leave an unfinished marking zecher l'churnan in compliance with the SA ([here](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.560?lang=bi)). Though some authorities opine that even a renter must leave a space if the owner did not. ([This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2228/15571) answer is related.)

Comment: Perhaps aspects of mezuza https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66555/759

Comment: related: [What are the halachic considerations that might come up when designing and building a house](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68765/11501)

Answer (score 1):

One of the very important things a person should do after becoming a homeowner is celebrate a *Chanukas Habayis*. He should show gratitude and appreciation for the great favor which Hashem has bestowed upon him in giving him the wonderful opportunity to become a homeowner. There is a Bracha which is recited when purchasing a new home. The bracha is [[Hatov V'Hametiv]](http://www.practicalhalacha.com/halacha/1217-shehecheyanu__acquisitions__when_to_bless_over_new?fs=1&r=6&st=Hatov%20Vehametiv), (this is generally so, as one is usually not the sole benefactor of a home purchase, as he also has a wife and family, who benefit from it.If he is the sole benefactor, he should say the Bracha of *Shecheyanu*).

I was personally told by Rav Chaim Kanievsky Shlita, in the name of his Father, the steipler Gaon ZTL, that those who become homeowners and do not celebrate chanukas Habayis, to show praise and gratitude to Hashem for their new home, are considered "*Kfuyey tovah*", guilty of denying the good that was done for them!